# Trimmed Mean with Percentage Limit in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the **trimmed mean**, which excludes the outliers, of an array.

I found there is a module called [`scipy.stats.tmean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.tmean.html#scipy.stats.tmean), but it requires the user specifies the **range by absolute value instead of percentage values**.

In Matlab, we have [`m = trimmean(X,percent)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/trimmean.html), that does exactly what I want.

**Do we have the counterpart in Python?**

Comment: I was interested in how difficult it would be to implement this, and I found a nice discussion of how a trimmed mean works: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4252/how-to-calculate-the-truncated-or-trimmed-mean

Answer (score 25):

At least for scipy v0.14.0, there is a dedicated function for this ([scipy.stats.trim_mean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.trim_mean.html)):

```
from scipy import stats
m = stats.trim_mean(X, 0.1) # Trim 10% at both ends
```

which used [`stats.trimboth`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.trimboth.html) inside.

From the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.1/scipy/stats/stats.py#L3343-L3410) it is possible to see that with `proportiontocut=0.1` the mean will be calculated using 80% of the data. Note that the `scipy.stats.trim_mean` can not handle `np.nan`.

Comment: This is documented at least for Scipy 0.17: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.trim_mean.html#scipy.stats.trim_mean

Answer (score 9):

(Edit: the context for this answer was that [`scipy.stats.trim_mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.trim_mean.html) wasn't documented yet. Now that it's publicly available, use that function instead of rolling your own. My answer below is kept for historical purpose.)

---

You can also implement the whole thing yourself, following the instruction in the MatLab documentation.

Here's the code in Python 2:

```py
from numpy import mean
def trimmean(arr, percent):
    n = len(arr)
    k = int(round(n*(float(percent)/100)/2))
    return mean(arr[k+1:n-k])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a manual implementation using floor from the math library...

```
def trimMean(tlist,tperc):
    removeN = int(math.floor(len(tlist) * tperc / 2))
    tlist.sort()
    if removeN > 0: tlist = tlist[removeN:-removeN]
    return reduce(lambda a,b : a+b, tlist) / float(len(tlist))
```

Comment: just for clarity, "tperc" confused me to use "10" as "percent", then formula needs /100 / 2. Otherwise it returns an empty list :) 

in above tperc is decimal notation/fraction of percentage.  0.1 for 10%.