# mean excluding outliers using Python (trimmean equivalent)

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, outliers

The data I have often has outliers. In Matlab, I used trimmean function which was very useful, but now I want to use Python. I tried looking up for a similar function but couldn't find one. I know you can use Matlab functions from Python using pymatlab of matlab engine, but I want to do this natively. (I found that using large numpy arrays with the Matlab engine is very slow which is a separate topic.). Is there a trimmean function in numpy or scipy?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19442484/5276734) it is suggested to write the function yourself in Python, which is quite easy and can be taken from the [Matlab help](http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/trimmean.html).

But [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.trim_mean.html#scipy.stats.trim_mean) contains a `trim_mean` function in `stats`.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.