# How to remove top and bottom nth% of data

Tags: python, numpy

I was creating a function to compute trimmed mean. To do this I removed highest and lowest percent of data and then the mean is computed as usual. What I have so far is :

```
def trimmed_mean(data, percent):
    from numpy import percentile

    if percent < 50:
        data_trimmed = [i for i in data
                        if i > percentile(data, percent)
                        and i < percentile(data, 100-percent)]
    else:
        data_trimmed = [i for i in data
                        if i < percentile(data, percent)
                        and i > percentile(data, 100-percent)]

    return sum(data_trimmed) / float(len(data_trimmed))
```

But I do get the wrong result. So, for `[37, 33, 33, 32, 29, 28, 28, 23, 22, 22, 22, 21, 21, 21, 20, 20, 19, 19, 18, 18, 18, 18, 16, 15, 14, 14, 14, 12, 12, 9, 6]` by 10% mean should be `20.16` while I get `20.0`.

Is there any other way to do removing top and bottom data in python? 
Or is there anything else that I have done wrong?

Comment: @Анастасия, perhaps there's no need to thank people for editing your question because there might be tens of them while the comment section will get flooded with thanks.

Comment: In the data that you gave, what should you get in the values for data_trimmed using 10%?

Comment: It should be data_trimmed =  [32, 29, 28, 28, 23, 22, 22, 22, 21, 21, 21, 20, 20, 19, 19, 18, 18, 18, 18, 16, 15, 14, 14, 14, 12]

Comment: should 12 be included in data_trimmed? percentile(data, 10) = 12.

Comment: Yes, 12 should be there.

Comment: I see. but there are two 12s in your data. should the other one be skipped? or in a general sense, if we have multiple values for either top or bottom, should we keep just one and exclude the rest?

Comment: There is to be just one 12 in final dataset. It is more to reduce the length of data set by n% of highest or lowest values. That is, if you trim 100 items dataset by 10% you remove 10% highest and 10% lowest so that you are left with 80 items. For multiple values it depends on if they fall in 10 items to be excluded.

Comment: I  see. ok, now i get it. I'll add my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take a look at this related question:[Trimmed Mean with Percentage Limit in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441730/trimmed-mean-with-percentage-limit-in-python)

In short for scipy version > 0.14.0 the following does the job

```
from scipy import stats
m = stats.trim_mean(X, percentage)
```

If you do not want to have an dependency on an external library then you can of course revert to an approach as shown in Chip Grandits answer.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest sorting the array first and then just take a "slice in the the middle."

```
#some "fancy" numpy sort or even just plain old sorted()
#sorted_data = sorted(data) #uncomment to use plain python sorted 
n = len(sorted_data)
outliers = n*percent/100 #may want some rounding logic if n is small
trimmed_data = sorted_data[outliers: n-outliers]
```

Comment: with floor division outliers = n*percent//100 it works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
import numpy as np
def trimmed_mean(data, percent):
    data = np.array(sorted(data))
    trim = int(percent*data.size/100.0)
    return data[trim:-trim].mean()
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this'll work:

```
data = [37, 33, 33, 32, 29, 28, 28, 23, 22, 22, 22, 21, 21, 21, 20, 20, 19, 19, 18, 18, 18, 18, 16, 15, 14, 14, 14, 12, 12, 9, 6]
percent = .1 # == 10%

def trimmed_mean(data, percent):
    # sort list
    data = sorted(data)
    # number of elements to remove from both ends of list
    g = int(percent * len(data))
    # remove elements
    data = data[g:-g]
    # cast sum to float to avoid implicit casting to int
    return float(sum(data)) / len(data)

print trimmed_mean(data, percent)
```

Output:

```
$ python trimmed_mean.py 
20.16
```